# Copy File Path in Code Compare

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am looking through a changeset in Team Explorer and I have opened a file in the built in code compare tool. On the left is the source code for the current working baseline's version of this file and on the right is the new one with the proposed changes. On the top of both of these views is a toolbar displaying the location of said file usually in the format of

```
$/Baseline Name/Build Name/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/FileName.cpp;CXXX
```

where CXXX refers to Changeset Number, XXX being the number.

I want to copy this directory, preferably starting at Dir1 and going all the way to the file extension. However, the problem comes the moment I click on this toolbar to select the path and copy it, it automatically changes the directory listing to where the local copy of the file exists, which is a random directory, with a random file name completely different from what its really called in the build.

I assumed something like holding alt, or shift, or ctrl while trying to select the directory would force it not to change, but that is not the case. Is there any way to make that directory listing selectable? If not, is there an easier way to obtain the directory correctly? I have to do this at least 30 times, so just selecting from that toolbar would be the ideal, quickest solution I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in VS2015 + TFS2015, there is no way to copy the path from compare tool. You can go to History and find the Changeset, then you can copy this Changeset:

[image]